# Angular material responsive ui

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, angularjs-material

I  have to develop a responsive ui in angular material css. I which i have arrange the div as its come 4 div in one row in lg screen and 2 in md and 1 on sm  screen. for that i have wrote the fallowing code but is not working as expected.

```
<div layout="row">
                            <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-md="25">Name :</div>
                            <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-md="25">Rhushikesh G. lokahnde</div>
                            <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-md="25">Date of Birth :</div>
                            <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-md="25">25th August 1990</div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `flex-sm`, `flex-md` and `flex-gt`? How does your actual code work? It would be nice to emphasize actual vs expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add layout-wrap else it wont wrap and the content will be on 1 row.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options